# Hibernate: ArrayList as a part of composite key

Tags: hibernate, key, composite

I have an entity describing the GPX track:

```
package my.domain;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

public class Track implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -9138958070798036048L;
    private List<TrackSegment> track;
    private Id id;
    private long trackId;

    @Autowired
    private Account account;

    public Track() {
        this.track = new ArrayList<>();
        this.id = new Id();
    }

    public Id getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Id id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void addSegment( TrackSegment trkseg ) {
        track.add(trkseg);
    }

    public List<TrackSegment> getTrack() {
        return track;
    }

    public void setTrack( List<TrackSegment> track ) {
        this.track = track;
    }

    public long getTrackId() {
        return trackId;
    }

    public void setTrackId(long trackId) {
        this.trackId = trackId;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        this.id.setCustomerId(account.getParentAccountId());
    }

    public void setCreateDate(Date createDate) {
        this.id.setCreateDate(createDate);
    }
}
```

Id.java:

```
package my.domain;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

public class Id implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -9118607746459983559L;
    private long customerId;
    private List<Date> createDate;
    private long trackId;

    public Id() {
        this.createDate = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public long getCustomerId() {
        return customerId;
    }

    public void setCustomerId(long customerId) {
        this.customerId = customerId;
    }

    public List<Date> getCreateDate() {
        return createDate;
    }

    public void setCreateDate(Date createDate) {
        this.createDate.add(createDate);
    }

    public long getTrackId() {
        return trackId;
    }

    public void setTrackId(long trackId) {
        this.trackId = trackId;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result
                + ((createDate == null) ? 0 : createDate.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + (int) (customerId ^ (customerId >>> 32));
        result = prime * result + (int) (trackId ^ (trackId >>> 32));
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Id other = (Id) obj;
        if (createDate == null) {
            if (other.createDate != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!createDate.equals(other.createDate))
            return false;
        if (customerId != other.customerId)
            return false;
        if (trackId != other.trackId)
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

As you can see, Id is a key with a pair of customer ID and create date (which is unique per customer).

Tracks.hbm.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="my.domain.domain.Track" table="TRACKS" schema="DBO" dynamic-update="true" dynamic-insert="true" batch-size="30">
        <composite-id name="id" class="my.domain.domain.Id" unsaved-value="undefined">
            <key-property name="customerId" type="long">
                <column name="CUSTOMERID" not-null="true"/>
            </key-property>
            <key-property name="createDate" type="date">
                <column name="CREATEDATE" not-null="true"/>
            </key-property>
        </composite-id>
        <component name="track" class="my.domain.domain.TrackSegment">
            <property name="longitude" type="double">
                <column name="LONGITUDE"  not-null="true"/>
            </property>
            <property name="latitude" type="double">
                <column name="LATITUDE" not-null="true" />
            </property>
            <property name="altitude" type="double">
                <column name="ALTITUDE" not-null="true" />
            </property>
            <property name="pointTime" type="timestamp">
                <column name="POINTTIME" not-null="true" length="7" />
            </property>
        </component>
        <property name="trackId" type="long">
            <column name="TRACKID"  not-null="true"/>
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

After the parsing of input XML, the instance of Track class is a complete container with a GPX data ready for saving. But when I try to persist the entity, Hibernate throws an exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.Date
>       at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.JdbcDateTypeDescriptor.extractHashCode(JdbcDateTypeDescriptor.java:40)
>       at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.getHashCode(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:214)
>       at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.getHashCode(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:218)
>       at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.getHashCode(ComponentType.java:257)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.spi.EntityKey.generateHashCode(EntityKey.java:76)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.spi.EntityKey.(EntityKey.java:71)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.generateEntityKey(AbstractSessionImpl.java:248)
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:172)
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:135)
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:206)
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:55)
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:191)
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:49)
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:683)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:675)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:671)
>       at my.domain.domain.dao.impl.TrackDaoImpl.saveTrack(TrackDaoImpl.java:41)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
>       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
>       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
>       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy17.saveTrack(Unknown Source)
>       at my.domain.utilities.NMEAData.saveGPX(NMEAData.java:97)
>       at my.domain.Main.main(Main.java:49)

Where I am wrong? Does Hibernate support the lists in composite keys?

Thank you.

Comment: Well you have told Hibernate that it's a `Date` and it's a `List`. What do you expect to happen? Further, how do you expect to use a `List` to be used as a primary key? It needs to be stored in a separate table. Sorry, but this ain't going to work - use a synthetic id.

Comment: The issue is resolved. I completely changed the logic and now it works fine.